# Correct way to create SparkSession on a Docker container

Tags: scala, docker, apache-spark

Having this docker-compose https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark what should be the correct ***master*** section to create from outside the Docker?

```
        // Scala
        val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
            .appName("beg_You_for_help")
            .master("spark://<host_?>:<port_?>")
            .getOrCreate()
```

Many thanks in advance to anyone for help.

Comment: I never thing you should set master like this, you do that on spark-submit, spark-shell, more flexible.

Comment: Would normally agree on that, but let's just assume I want to follow this way, ie., when running the code from IntelliJ with the master host and port being hardcoded.

Comment: newer area for me, I like the SBT mode, but am really an architect so I let the experts answer but I saw a few postings on this